# Do v2 Google Cloud Functions not have regions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

So I've been deploying v2 functions now and I just noticed that they don't seem to have regions weirdly enough

I can create a function called "test-endpoint" in two completely different regions i.e asia-southeast2 and us-central1

Then both functions will have the same trigger url i.e: https://test-endpoint-klakmdw932-as.a.run.app

How does Google actually know which region I want to hit? Seems very confusing to me

Also, 2nd question I noticed to matter what region I select the IP address used for requests whether I'm using v1 or v2 cloud functions is always a US one. Does this mean Google Cloud routes all cloud function egress through US data centers?

Honestly seems like a really strange setup and just something that'd add latency

Comment: The service you are using to lookup the IP address is returning the business address for Google. That unfortunately does not provide correct details on the region where the IP address is used.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As @John Hanley mentioned:

> The service you are using to lookup the IP address is returning the business address for Google. That unfortunately does not provide correct details on the region where the IP address is used.

---

References:

- [Cloud Functions Locations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations)
- [Optimizing Networking](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking)
- [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing)
- [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn)